# What are state while executing NSOperation

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I have done NSOperation demo example,After read document and blog i came to know when any operation add to queue have different state

> ready → executing → finished

In the demo from code of viewController.m like

```
#import "OperationViewController.h"
#import "TestOperation.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface OperationViewController ()
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSOperationQueue *queue;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *oprationArray;
@property(nonatomic,strong) TestOperation *operation1;
@property(nonatomic,strong) TestOperation *operation2;
@property(nonatomic,strong) TestOperation *operation3;
@property(nonatomic,strong) TestOperation *operation4;
@property(nonatomic,strong) TestOperation *operation5;
@end

static char CharForCurrentThread(void)
// Returns 'M' if we're running on the main thread, or 'S' otherwies.
{
    return [NSThread isMainThread] ? 'M' : 'S';
}

@implementation OperationViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //Case-1 First Initalisation
    _queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    _queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 4;

    _operation1 = [[TestOperation alloc] init];
    _operation1.countValue = 1;
    //op.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Operation-%d",i];
    [_operation1 setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Operation-%ld",(long)_operation1.countValue] forKey:@"name"]; //==

    _operation2 = [[TestOperation alloc] init];
    _operation2.countValue = 2;
    [_operation2 setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Operation-%ld",(long)_operation2.countValue] forKey:@"name"]; //==

    _operation3 = [[TestOperation alloc] init];
    _operation3.countValue = 3;
    //_operation3.queuePriority = NSOperationQueuePriorityVeryHigh;
    [_operation3 setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Operation-%ld",(long)_operation3.countValue] forKey:@"name"]; //==

    _operation4 = [[TestOperation alloc] init];
    _operation4.countValue = 4;
    [_operation4 setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Operation-%ld",(long)_operation4.countValue] forKey:@"name"]; //==

    _operation5 = [[TestOperation alloc] init];
    _operation5.countValue = 5;
    //_operation5.queuePriority = NSOperationQueuePriorityLow;
    [_operation5 setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Operation-%ld",(long)_operation5.countValue] forKey:@"name"]; // KVC complient

    //[_operation1 addDependency:_operation5];

//    [_operation5 addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"isFinished" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew|NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:nil];
//    [_operation5 addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"isExecuting" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew|NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:nil];

//    _oprationArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:_operation1,_operation2,_operation3,_operation4,_operation5, nil];
    _oprationArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:_operation1,_operation2,_operation3, nil];

    [_queue addOperations:_oprationArray waitUntilFinished:NO];
}

@end
```

and custom operation class like

```
#import "TestOperation.h"

@implementation TestOperation

- (void)main
{
    NSLog(@"Method main :%ld",(long)_countValue);
    NSLog(@"Operation Priority ::%ld",(long)self.queuePriority);
    if ([self isCancelled])
    {
        NSLog(@"Operation is Canceled ::%@",self.name);
    }

    if ([self isExecuting])
    {
        NSLog(@"Operation is Executing ::%@",self.name);
    }

    if ([self isFinished])
    {
        NSLog(@"Operation is Finished ::%@",self.name);
    }

    if ([self isConcurrent])
    {
        NSLog(@"Operation is Concurrent ::%@",self.name);
    }

    if ([self isAsynchronous])
    {
        NSLog(@"Operation is Asynchronous ::%@",self.name);
    }

    if ([self isReady])
    {
        NSLog(@"Operation is Ready ::%@",self.name);
    }    
}

-(BOOL)finished
{
    NSLog(@"Operation is Finished ::%@",self.name);
    return YES;
}

@end
```

As per documentation i was expecting state mentioned above (Ready -> Executing -> Finished), Even output does not show Finished state
But in the console like below:

```
2017-05-31 19:18:33.212 DemoData[16365:485789] Method main :1
2017-05-31 19:18:33.212 DemoData[16365:485919] Method main :2
2017-05-31 19:18:33.212 DemoData[16365:485921] Method main :4
2017-05-31 19:18:33.212 DemoData[16365:485920] Method main :3
2017-05-31 19:18:33.213 DemoData[16365:485789] Operation Priority ::0
2017-05-31 19:18:33.214 DemoData[16365:485919] Operation Priority ::0
2017-05-31 19:18:33.214 DemoData[16365:485921] Operation Priority ::0
2017-05-31 19:18:33.215 DemoData[16365:485920] Operation Priority ::0
2017-05-31 19:18:33.215 DemoData[16365:485789] Operation is Executing ::Operation-1
2017-05-31 19:18:33.216 DemoData[16365:485919] Operation is Executing ::Operation-2
2017-05-31 19:18:33.216 DemoData[16365:485921] Operation is Executing ::Operation-4
2017-05-31 19:18:33.217 DemoData[16365:485920] Operation is Executing ::Operation-3
2017-05-31 19:18:33.217 DemoData[16365:485789] Operation is Ready ::Operation-1
2017-05-31 19:18:33.218 DemoData[16365:485919] Operation is Ready ::Operation-2
2017-05-31 19:18:33.218 DemoData[16365:485921] Operation is Ready ::Operation-4
2017-05-31 19:18:33.220 DemoData[16365:485920] Operation is Ready ::Operation-3
2017-05-31 19:18:33.221 DemoData[16365:485789] Method main :5
2017-05-31 19:18:33.240 DemoData[16365:485789] Operation Priority ::0
2017-05-31 19:18:33.241 DemoData[16365:485789] Operation is Executing ::Operation-5
2017-05-31 19:18:33.241 DemoData[16365:485789] Operation is Ready ::Operation-5
2017-05-31 19:18:33.242 DemoData[16365:485789] queue has completed
```

Comment: Why do you think there is a problem with your output? An operation's `main` is called once. You check all of the states only while `main` is running. The output you see is just fine for the code you wrote.

Comment: Could you be more descriptive of what the question is here? I'm not certain what you need answered.

Comment: @rmaddy you are right `main` get called once. But in `main` method print check are random sequence, It must print only `Ready` state. In output you see it print `Executing` then `Ready`. where i would get "Finished" state of Operation.

Comment: An operation isn't finished until `main` has completed. So you can't get a finished state inside your `main`. And there is nothing random about the print sequence in your output.

Comment: @rmaddy thank you with KVO on operation object get finished state, One thing observed even operation not completed process (download data using service) still it return as  `Finished` state. After that control is in `main` method for executing task. How to pass those data to UI?